# About Infinitive

Tags: infinitives

I know that this sentence is correct:

> "He is not a man **to tell** a lie."

Is it also correct if I say

> "He is not a man **tell** a lie."

If it's correct what is the difference between these sentences? And when I use the infinitive without **to**, what is the theme in grammar?

Comment: "He is not a man **tell** a lie" is not grammatical. Using ellipsis you could say "He is not a man **tells** a lie," in which the "who" would be dropped from "who tells". When using the infinitive, you *have* to use *to*. It's the law.

Comment: Another relative infinitive construction; relative infinitives require the _to_, but do not allow relative pronouns, except with pied-piping, like _a lie with which to fool them_, but _a lie to fool them with_, and not **a lie which to fool them with*.

Comment: @Robusto I'm not saying you are wrong. But I would struggle to remember the last time I heard it.

Comment: @WS2. I have heard it in rural dialects, and you see it in writers like Twain et al. when they're affecting rural speech.

Comment: Consider- He is not a man you can lie to.

Comment: @Robusto Ok, "He _was_ not a man **tells** a lie" - is it correct too? Can i say "told" or "have told"?

Comment: I personally wouldn't use it unless you're *very* comfortable speaking that dialect, which I very much doubt you are.

Comment: You could say "I heard a man tell a lie." But I don't think that's an infinitive. On the other hand, it's not "tells" or "told". Perhaps someone could explain this.

Answer (score 1):

All English verbs have a base form, an inflected form, and a participial form. For regular verbs, the base form is the same as the inflected form for all person-number combinations other than 3sg. The base form is used in an infinitival construction, which requires the preposition **to**. The preposition **to** is also associated with a purposive meaning in certain constructions (e.g., *More than one way _to skin a cat_*). In Spanish or French, the infinitive form of the verb does not have purposive meaning by itself. A preposition (*para* or *pour*, for example) must be used to get that meaning.

I think that the reason for the question is that the OP might be familiar with a language like Spanish or French where an infinitival construction is formed using a specific inflection of the verb, and no associated preposition.

Answer (score 0):

'He is a not a man tell a lie'

This sententance is not gramatically correct, for when spoken, the natural way to say this is to split it into two parts.

'He is not a man, tell a lie' Which whilst abreviated, would work. If you are looking for other ways to say your beginning sentance, may I suggest;

He is a man who wouldn't tell a lie
He is not a man to be decietfull

Obviously, you can work this in a hundred different variations.

Lying is not in this mans nature
He would never lie to me